# Is there a "Coalgebra - Cogeometry" duality? Good opposite of a category of coalgebras?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, category-theory, coalgebras

So the category of affine schemes is dual to the category of commutative rings, Stone spaces are dual to Boolean algebras, localizable measurable spaces are dual to commutative Von Neumann algebras, and I'm sure there are many more examples. In general, a category of algebraic structures is going to be dual to some related category of geometric structures.

My question is, then: is there an analogous story for coalgbraic things? If I take a category of coalgebras for some comonad and flip the arrows around, will I get something interesting? Are there any good examples of this over familiar comonads (say, the costate comonad)?

Comment: "In general, a category of geometric structures is going to be dual to some related category of algebraic structures." - No. For example, the category of schemes (or the category of manifolds) has no reasonable algebraic dual category. It is vice versa: Often, starting with an algebraic category, the dual turns out to be "affine" geometric. (Whatever this means.)

Comment: (Cocommutative) coalgebras are formal spaces. This is not a duality: the correspondence is covariant rather than contravariant.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks I'll change the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

If $R$ is a commutative ring, then the category of commutative bialgebras (resp. Hopf algebras) over $R$ is dual to the category of affine monoid (resp. group) schemes over $R$. This may be seen as an extension of the duality between commutative algebras over $R$ and affine schemes over $R$. However, I don't know any geometric description of coalgebras over $R$.

Comment: If $R$ is a field, cocommutative coalgebras over $R$ are the ind-category of finite-dimensional cocommutative coalgebras over $R$, which is dual to the category of finite-dimensional commutative algebras over $R$; this is itself dual to a category of formal varieties, and hence the original category of coalgebras is a category of "ind-formal" varieties.

Comment: Why don't you make this to an answer? This is not a comment to my answer.